# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "150", but I've tried everything, How can I fix this error?

Tags: java, arraylist, error-handling, compiler-errors, numberformatexception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "150"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:836)
        at Median.main(Median.java:45)
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Median {
    
    public static Long selection(ArrayList<Long> numbers, int k) throws IOException {
        long pivot = numbers.get(0); //Line 8
        ArrayList<Long> left = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> middle = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> right = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++) {
            if(numbers.get(i) < pivot) {
                left.add(numbers.get(i)); 
            }
            else if(numbers.get(i) == pivot) {
                middle.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            else {
                right.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
        }
        middle.add(pivot);

        if(k <= left.size()) {
            return selection(left, k);
        }
        else if(left.size() < k && k <= right.size()) {
            return middle.get(0);
        }
        else {
            return selection(right, k-left.size() - middle.size());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Long> numsList = new ArrayList<Long>();

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("manhattanAirBnbPrivateRoomPrices.txt"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        String [] integers = line.trim().split("\n");
        for(String integer: integers) {
            numsList.add(Long.parseLong(integer)); // Line 45
        }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int position = numsList.size();
        if((numsList.size() % 2) == 0) {
            position = numsList.size() / 2;
        }
        else {
            position = (int) numsList.size() / 2;
        }

        selection(numsList, position); 
    }
}
```

I've tried everything with Integer as the data type for everything (return type in selection method, ArrayList types, etc.) and it has the same error on line 45. I am reading from a text file using BufferedReader, but I tried using Scanner at first, but there was an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error when trying to execute line 8 (long pivot = numbers.get(0);), so I switched it and that error went away, but came with this other one. What can I do to fix it, it sees like there's no way I can read the first line in the text file (150) because apparently its too large to be an integer and it just doesn't work when I changed everything to be of type long?!?!

Comment: What it means is that you (and only you) need to do more debugging. Use your debugger and find out *exactly* what text is causing the problem, get the text itself, analyze each char to make sure that they are standard digits that represent numeric entities, etc... Again, this is something that you and only you can do at this time.

Comment: Also, for our purposes, you *must* post the complete stack trace from the exception in your question, the full beast as code-formatted text. Also, post the actual text in the text file that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, as @OldDogProgrammer states, all important information, especially error information and code, should be in the question itself as an [edit], and not in comments. Use comments to notify us when you've made such changes to the question.

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data in the input file?

Comment: Your original error was because of *i <= numbers.size()*. The upper bound is *out* of bounds. But it's no good if you don't show us to *what* you "switched" your code as a result

Comment: There's likely an unprintable character in the text line - such as the following produces your exact error showing as `"150"`: `Long.parseLong("150\1");` - be sure to view your text file in hex mode as well.  It's also likely not a `\r` since it would have affected the output error message.

Comment: This, is a problem: `split("\n");`. You should use the system's line separator, not `"\n"`

Comment: `String[] lines = string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Comment: Or `String[] lines = string.split("\\R");` or `String[] lines = string.split("\\s*\\R\\s*");` to swallow any extra whitespace

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just learned something new from you today, `\R`. Cheers!

Comment: You can do `System.lineSeparator()` too